# promote google maps api without showing my key

Tags: google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3, webapi, api-key

i have a google maps api key. full packet (javascript api - geocoding - streetview another etc..)

Google creates an image on the map (it becomes img src), but my request is not to show the api key when assigning this link, the image page to my potential customer.

Example link below (YOUR_API_KEY part) if you enter the api key, the image will appear, but it is meaningless to throw it like this, if I put the api key, it can also use it..

[Click to show image](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1000x600&path=enc%3AuypyFkxxoDcAY%5BWWa@kA%7DBg@q@_@WYKSEq@Gy@Bs@Xe@Z_AhA%7BAvByDbFoAxA%5Df@%5Bx@O%60AEdA@%60@NpATjALd@fA%60BPZRx@ThBFpBCdAWjBYvAGRIHaB%7CD?L%7D@tBc@nAg@%60Bk@rAc@p@e@h@_@V%7B@%5Eq@Li@B%5D?aAMc@Mu@%5DeCqAoAk@cAYkASqAG_BB%7DF%5C%5CsFZeFXwGf@qFb@gH%7E@aCVsAF%7D@AoAKqAWsDw@cCk@W?aB%5BsDu@aFgAeFkA_A%5Bc@KsC%7D@uCiAsDeBkCiAaCs@iB_@kBYwD_@aEUkBBcENeBNoFh@mCNs@@mC?eDQqBSkCi@cAe@wAm@yBkAqG%7BDwBqAMSyF_EaAu@iDoCeB_BqA%7BAg@%7B@_@y@a@mAc@cB_@oCUoDk@yMKiFSgHOu@OcGMeCOsEMuEIcCQkGKeGKeEe@cIcA_NsAeMUyBMkADm@e@cHGkBE%7DE?_DH%7BE%5EoKPkEJkCZcEl@gFZwAxAcIRmAJMTu@h@wBf@wAlAiCj@y@dAgAxA%7B@NQH_@@QIk@OUWQgDeBmFaDwA%7B@YAkB%7BAu@c@gD%7BBaDoBmGuDkA_Ay@_Ai@s@uAwB_AcBk@uAsAyDc@aBUcAScAU_A_@gCa@wCSiBEo@%5BiEQ_DWeBFi@B%7BAHwAFg@R%7DD@gEIiBk@yG%7D@_KOoCaAqLQ_B%5BaB_@%7BAa@mAwCwIs@uBmA_EP%5Di@sCIo@?WBu@JuA%5C%5CwB?a@SgAGUGU%5DBWD_AE%5BA%7B@Co@BaBDyAAsEWu@Uk@c@WSm@MyBU%7D@Gk@Ma@ISK%5DYMo@GS@?@E?C?GCEIE%5DyAa@uBOg@_@q@g@k@WOYIY@s@aAGOMk@%5Bw@CSA%5D?mAEi@Ck@?O&key=YOUR_API_KEY)

What is your suggestion?

Comment: with Google Maps you can restrict the use of you apikey only for your server/path ..  so if someone others see the keyy can'use it... you can assigne the allowed  domain in the google maps config platform

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Proxy the request through your server
2. Use signed urls (turn quota to zero for unsigned requests) for static maps. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key for more information.